# How is garbage collection done in Java and how does it compare to .net?

Tags: java, .net

I am wondering what the differences are or if it is the same across both.

Comment: Would the people voting to close this as "not a real question" care to explain their motives? It's not like the guy has 100 rep.

Comment: Part 1 ('how is gc done in Java') has been covered by dozens of questions on SO.

Comment: @Andreas to quote Dylan "If there's an original thought out there I could use one right now." Every question has been asked on SO by now. But if people want to close it as a duplicate, at least choose that option from the menu because it gives the OP references to the other posts.

Comment: @CodeToGlory: despite the crazy close-voters (SO at its worst) my only comment is that AFAIK the way the garbage collector operates in Java is **not** fixed by the specs. Hence different JVMs will have different type of GC.  Heck, in a same JVM, depending on the machine it is run on (depending on your machine the JVM may run in client or server mode by itself) or the JVM parameters you're giving, you can have different type of GCs.

Comment: Who asked for a duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2910224/java-garbage-collection (First hit after searching "[java] [c#] garbage" and the next 3 search results look promising too ...). Sorry for my opinion - I think that people with 4k rep should use search.

Comment: I am utilizing the automatic search that comes up when I type the question. Isn't that sufficient to tell me that it is duplicate? Then maybe the question is to fix the duplication question recommendation first and not try to close this question.

Also, would it not simply help to post the link as an answer if there was indeed an existing question, which I would then accept and close myself.

Comment: I am mainly looking if the algorithm is similar to Mark and Sweep in both .Net and Java. Jeez guys they are so many trigger happy guys here that simply want to close the question. If you do not know the answer just move on.

Comment: Perhaps he doesn't have 100 rep because people continue upvoting questions like this which are clear duplicates.

Comment: @jasonmp85 did you read the answers for the duplicates posted here? Please read before you blindly leave a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this [link](http://www.25hoursaday.com/CsharpVsJava.html#heap) from my other [question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2933559/what-is-the-best-way-to-learn-java-and-start-following-the-latest-and-greatest-fo) that answers a little bit about the differences of garbage collection in Java and .NET/C#. For others who are looking for this kind of information, here it is-

> In Java objects are created on the
>   heap using the new keyword. Most
>   classes in C# are created on the heap
>   by using the new keyword. Also just as
>   the JVM manages the destruction of
>   objects so also does the CLR via a
>   Mark and Compact garbage collection
>   algorithm
>
> NOTE: C# also supports stack-based
>   classes, called value types, which are
>   discussed further below.

Comment: http://www.brpreiss.com//books/opus5/html/page428.html has good info and Marc and compact algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

This question is not answerable.

Firstly, none of the relevant specifications will say anything about *how* Java or .net should implement garbage collection.  So there is literally no "way that GC is done" in Java or in .net.

Secondly, the details of how GC is implemented differs between the various vendors for Java and .net respectively, and for any vendor the GC may change with each platform, each major version, minor version and even each patch version.  On top of that, some implementations of Java allow you to choose between different garbage collectors using command line options.

Finally, it doesn't really matter how the GC is implemented in a Java or .net implementation *provided* that it can be made to work as required by the application.  And for Java, the answer is that it can for most kinds of application.  (The exceptions are typically systems/applications with hard real time requirements or very tight memory constraints.)

Comment: But for some background theory and basics: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2910224/java-garbage-collection/2922042#2922042

Comment: @Andreas_D - there are more detailed descriptions of the Java GC around than the one referenced.  And both of the referenced pages are old.  The Java GCs have definitely changed significantly since 1.4.1.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose there is no conceptual difference.
Since memory models are slighlty different([for example volative difference](http://igoro.com/archive/volatile-keyword-in-c-memory-model-explained/)), realization may vary.

Comment: Maybe no conceptual difference on a high level (i.e. garbage collection on both platforms has the same function - clean up objects that aren't referenced anymore), but there are a number of different algorithms to do this, so there are major differences in implementation, even between different versions of Sun's JVM, for example.

Comment: IMHO if you need to worry about how GC works in 99% means you don't need GC at all.